# IntegrityError at /admin/main/category/add/ NOT NULL constraint failed: main_category.author_id

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm not sure why this error is occuring. It's occuring after I have restricted only one category is created by one user. But I want to be able to create multiple category pages inside admin page. I have tried creating category pages through admin page, and it gives me errors:

```
IntegrityError at /admin/main/category/add/
NOT NULL constraint failed: main_category.author_id
```

I'm not even sure where it's happening.

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/main/category/add/
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_category.author_id
```

IntegrityError

```
Exception Value:    
Exception Location: /Desktop/ebagu0.2/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 318
Python Executable:  Desktop/ebagu0.2/env/bin/python
```

My model

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.name,instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my view

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        return render(request,'main/category_already_exists.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

my admin

```
class CatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}
    fields = ['name', 'slug']
```

Comment: Is this SQLite3? I'm looking at the file path in your exception location.

Comment: yes, is it occuring from there?I'm still in my local that I'm willing to delete and re install db

Comment: Your view is completely irrelevant, as this error is happening in the admin. Its logic is correct, in that it would solve this problem if it had been happening there, but it isn't: your error clearly shows it is happening in the admin Add Category page. You need some way of using that logic there.

Comment: Based on your error, you're trying to save a `main_category` without specifying an `author_id`. Looking at your view, maybe `request.user` isn't set when it's assigned to author. If author is a required field, there should be a check for that in your admin.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for another good hint, what do you mean by admin addCategory Page?I mean where should I fix?where is the problem occuring?

Comment: I don't understand your question, or your confusion. You must know what page you are on when you get the error; and if for some impossible reason you really don't know, the message tells you: you are on "/admin/main/category/add/". That is the Add Category page in the admin.

Comment: And the reason for the error is that you have only included the name and slug fields in your admin class for Category, so author will always be None, and you've forbidden that in the definition of the author field.

Comment: @Patrick Lee,@DanielRoseman, adding author field to admin page has fixed the error but author is shown as annonymous whereas I want the author to be my name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exception Value: NOT NULL constraint failed: main_category.author_id
```

You forgot to set the `author` via the admin:

```
class CatAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('name',)}
    fields = ['name', 'slug', 'author']
    #                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Depending on your needs, you might want to make the `author` field optional:

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    ...
    # remove unique=True, add null=True
    author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True)
    #                                                       ^^^^^^^^^
    ...
```

By the way, note that with a non-null `OneToOneField`, specifying `unique=True` is superfluous.